# How to set a custom object in a JTable row

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablemodel

I should tell this first, this is NOT about Rendering a Table cell.

Here is the TableModel that i'm building using a 2D array based on a `User` object in my DB.

```
    List<User> userList = userManagerService.getAllUsers();

    /* String[] col_user = {"Username", "Name", "Phone", .... } */
    String[][] data = new String[userList.size()][col_user.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (User user : userList) {
        String[] userdata = new String[col_user.length];
        userdata[0] = user.getUserUsername();
        userdata[1] = user.getUserName();
        userdata[2] = user.getUserPhone();
        userdata[3] = user.getUserNic();
        userdata[4] = user.getUserAddress();
        userdata[5] = user.getUserEmail();

        data[i++] = userdata;
    }

    VstTableItemModel tiModel = new VstTableItemModel(data, col_user);
    dataTable.setModel(tiModel);
```

My problem is how can i get a `User` object back, using the selected row in the Table. Note that i can't make a new `User` object and populate it with the row data. I must get the queried `User` object(objects in `userList`). So, is their any way to set a Object with a table row ?

Here is my `VstTableItemModel` class.

```
public class VstTableItemModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    ArrayList<Object[]> data;
    String[] header;

    public VstTableItemModel(Object[][] obj, String[] header) {
        this.header = header;
        data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
            data.add(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return header.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int index) {
        return header[index];
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the `VstTableItemModel`?

Comment: Yes. Do i need to post it here ?

Comment: No, it will just make it easier ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of splitting the `User` object up before you create the model, add it directly to the model and allow the model to do the work for you...

For example

```
public class VstTableItemModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<User> users;

    public VstTableItemModel(List<User> users) {

        this.users = new ArrayList<User>(users);

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Object value = "??";
        User user = users.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = user.getUserUsername();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = user.getUserName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = user.getUserPhone();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = user.getUserNic();
                break;
            case 4:
                value = user.getUserAddress();
                break;
            case 5:
                value = user.getUserEmail();
                break;
        }

        return value;

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return // Return the class that best represents the column...
    }

    /* Override this if you want the values to be editable...
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //....
    }
    */

    /**
     * This will return the user at the specified row...
     * @param row
     * @return 
     */
    public User getUserAt(int row) {
        return users.get(row);
    }

}
```

This way, you should be able to do something like...

```
List<User> userList = userManagerService.getAllUsers();
VstTableItemModel tiModel = new VstTableItemModel(userList);
```

Now when you need to...you can grab a the user that is represent at a specific row...

```
User user = tiModel.getUserAt(rowIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks. But, What will happen if i sort it ? Then the row index will change. isn't it ?

Comment: If you're using `JTable`'s sort API, then you can simply use `JTable. convertRowIndexToModel` to convert the view's (the `JTable`) row index to the model index.

Comment: I should point out, the row sorter API (`TableRowSorter`) uses a proxy model when sorting, it doesn't actually change the data model, but instead maps the indices between the view and the model

Comment: Glad I helped someone today :D